# Why do we need @SubComponent in Dagger 2?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

What is the use of `@Subcomponent` in our application?

```
  @Subcomponent
    interface PostActivitySubComponent : AndroidInjector<PostsActivity> {

        @Subcomponent.Builder
        abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<PostsActivity>()
    }
```

The application works fine with and without this component. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Subcomponent is a mechanism that allows scope inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

`@SubComponent` is very helpful for the large application where Activities/Fragments where you provide dependencies for the specefic screen. For example you have `AppComponent` and `SubComponent` named `ProfileDetailedComponent` and you have no posssibility to control memory , but `SubComponent` help to you control memory with `@Scope`. For the each screen you will create `SubComponent` and `SubComponent` annotated all provides with `@CustomScope` and when user leave current screen , you can clear current component and free up memory , in the `onDestroy()` method. In sum `@SubComponent` need to contol your application memory.